# MinGW\bin/ld: invalid subsystem type gui

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, raylib

I am trying to compile a c++ program with raylib(maybe unrelated).
I have followed this tutorial:
https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Use-raylib-with-Sublime-Text
the only difference in my version of the batch file is "SET "COMPILER=%RAYLIB_DIR%\w64devkit\bin\g++.exe"(this file is included with the windows installation file for raylib mingw version) I'm very new type of stuff so this is where I'm must unsure about.

When I try to compile with this configuration I get the error

```
cc1plus.exe: warning: command-line option '-std=c99' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++

C:\MinGW\bin/ld: invalid subsystem type gui

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

im unsure as to why it is using the C:\MinGW dir, i do believe i have it installed there aswell however.

I have tried tcc, which has worked once, it has began spitting even more errors out,
however I'm trying to use a c++ compiler, I have used zig as well, it seems to have made a broken exe file that didn't seem to run, zig also gives errors during compilation.

Comment: Maybe you have a library that requires a more modern C++ standard. You are compiling against C++99, so you can try C++11 or newer. You should also take into account whether you are compiling for 32bit or 64bit and modify your toolchain/config accordingly

Comment: compiling with -std=c2x does remove the first error.

Comment: ld are linker-related errors, so you are probably compiling agains the wrong architecture for a certain library, or paths are wrong, or similar. You could enable verbose output in order to get a detailed output and then post it here.